# Screen Tearing while scrolling chrome xubuntu

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, tearing

Scrolling through pages with lots of images cause a distortion about 2/3 down the screen. I've tried enabling/disabling smooth scroll and in chrome. I've also tried toggling compositor settings on device. I'm not really sure what the best bet solution here is. I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated!

Here's a device info dump:

-Computer-

- Processor        : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
- Memory       : 8075MB (3935MB used)
- Operating System     : Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- User Name        : nick-bbytes (Nick-BBytes)
- Date/Time        : Mon 06 Feb 2017 01:03:12 PM EST

-Display-

- Resolution       : 3840x1080 pixels
- OpenGL Renderer      : Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
- X11 Vendor       : The X.Org Foundation

-Multimedia-

- Audio Adapter        : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
- Audio Adapter        : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH

-Input Devices-

- Lid Switch
- Sleep Button
- Power Button
- AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
- Video Bus
- USB Optical Mouse
- USB-HID Keyboard
- USB-HID Keyboard
- ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
- HDA Intel PCH Mic
- HDA Intel PCH Headphone
- HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm       : 3=
- HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm       : 7=
- HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm       : 8=
- Asus WMI hotkeys
- USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam

-SCSI Disks-

- ATA Micron_M600_MTFD

Answer (score 6):

This may be caused by Chrome falling back to software rendering which is not vsync'ed.

Check `chrome://gpu/` and see if hardware acceleration is enabled (shows green for all features). If it's not, enable the `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist` flag. Check `chrome://gpu/` again to see if hardware acceleration is enabled now.